# Can anyone help me break this recursion

Tags: python, recursion

This is a problem from yesterday's leetcode question (Check if There is a Valid Partition For The Array
) I think I did the code but I just don't know how to break recursion if the list is empty []. Even if the list is empty, in this code, it will continue traversing the tree until every node is visited

```
class Solution:
    def validPartition(self, nums: [int]) -> bool:
        memo = {}
        s = nums
        k = 0
        return self.partitionHelper(nums, s, memo, k)

    def partitionHelper(self, nums, s, memo, k) -> bool:
        key = tuple(nums)
        if key in memo:
            return memo[key]
        if nums == []:
            return True
        if len(nums) == 1:
            return False
        if len(nums) == 2 and nums[0] != nums[1]:
            return False
        elif len(nums) == 3 and ((nums[0]+nums[1]+nums[2])/3) != nums[1]:
            return False
        memo[key] = self.partitionHelper(nums=s[k:k+2], k=k+2,  s=s, memo=memo) + \
            self.partitionHelper(nums=s[k:k+3], k=k+3, s=s, memo=memo)
        return False


s = Solution()
print(s.validPartition(nums=[4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]))
```

Comment: just put a counter with an `if` statement in it somewhere...  that is standard practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your attempt:

- `((nums[0]+nums[1]+nums[2])/3) != nums[1]` is not a good test: it would give the wrong result when `nums[0:3]` is a **descending** sequence, like [5, 4, 3].
- `memo[key] = ...` assigns a *sum* and thus becomes an integer, not a boolean, yet the return value should always be a boolean. You should use an `or` operator instead of `+`
- The `return False` below that assignment does not reflect the result. It could be `False` or `True`, depending on what was just assigned to `memo[key]`. You should return `memo[key]`
- `key = tuple(nums)` is the wrong way to use memoization, because it depends where this 2/3 slice occurs in the `nums` input. If you find that `nums[100:103]` cannot lead to a valid partition, the same slice may occur at `nums[20:23]` and **do** lead to a valid partition, or vice versa. This really means you have to use a different key for memoization. It should be based on `k`, where `memo[k]` means *"can I find a valid partition from index `k` onwards?"*

Not a problem, but I would not pass the 2-3 sized slice as an argument to your helper function. Instead determine if you have a valid slice and make the recursion (when it is valid) and just pass the increased `k`. You can also save some parameters by placing the helper function inside the scope of the main method.

Here is how I would write it:

```
class Solution:
    def validPartition(self, nums: [int]) -> bool:
        n = len(nums)
        # memo: memo[k] == True means that there is no valid partition for `nums[k:]`
        #       memo[k] == False means we have not determined that yet.
        memo = [False] * n   

        def partitionHelper(k) -> bool:
            if k >= n - 1:  # base cases
                return k == n
            if memo[k]:
                return False # Already known to not give a solution
            a, b = nums[k:k+2]
            if k <= n - 3 and (a == b == nums[k + 2] or a == b - 1 == nums[k + 2] - 2) and partitionHelper(k + 3):
                return True  # Found one partition, get out of recursion
            if a == b and partitionHelper(k + 2):
                return True  # Found one partition, get out of recursion
            # No possibility to partition from this k-index onwards
            memo[k] = True  # Make sure we don't try this again
            return False

        return partitionHelper(0)
```

Comment: This is a really good explanation, easy to follow and perfectly shown. Thank you! I learn quite a few things from your post

Answer (score 0):

You can vastly simplify your code if you use @cache, which does memoization for you, and use internal functions, so that you don't have to keep copying your arguments.

```
class Solution:
    def validPartition(self, nums: [int]) -> bool:
        @cache
        def first_n_are_partition(n):
            """returns True iff the first n elements of nums are a partition"""
            if n == 0:
                return True
            if n == 1:
                return False
            if n == 2:
                return nums[0] == nums[1]
            a, b, c = nums[n - 3], nums[n - 2], nums[n - 1]
            return (b == c and first_n_are_partition(n - 2)) or \
                   ((a == b == c or a < b < c) and first_n_are_partition(n - 3))

        return first_n_are_partition(len(nums))
```